# Can I install a new SR release for an Eclipse version by simply overwriting files?

Tags: eclipse, installation, upgrade, overwrite

I just downloaded Eclipse Kepler SR2 (for Linux, 64 bits). I have non-SR Kepler, with some packages installed. Now, can I just un-tar-gzip the installation archive into my eclipse folder, and run? Or will this break things?

Answer (score 0):

It may break things as the Eclipse 'p2' installation manager will not understand what has happened.

You can use unpack it in to a new directory and use that (you will have to install any other plugins).

Normally you use `Help > Check for Updates` to update existing Eclipse installations.

Comment: My machine is not connected to the Internet, so I can't check for updates :-(